# Inequalities between Integrals of 3 Complex functions

Tags: integration

suppose I have three functions, f(x), g(x) and h(x). I want to know if there are any bounds on the integrals of these quantities. Specifically if I can measure a and b where
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)g^*(x)|^2dx=a
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)h^*(x)|^2dx=b
\end{equation}
Is there an upper bound on c where c is defined below?
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}|h(x)g^*(x)|^2dx=c
\end{equation}

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, at least among smooth functions.  Take smooth functions $f$ and $g = h$ such that $f$ is non-zero only for $|x-1| < \frac12$ and $g = h$ is non-zero only for $|x-2|< \frac12$, then $a = b = 0$ while $c$ can be arbitrary large.

Comment: There are easy counter-examples. Take $f=1$ and $g=h$ where $g \in L^{2}\setminus L^{4}$.